# What values can I change when replacing a 200uH 2Amp coupled inductor?

Tags: inductor, repair

I am replacing a coupled inductor (with corrosion on it) on a liquid handling robot board, in hopes to fix a blowing fuse problem.  The part number is not coming up in any search I have tried so far, and a replacement part of the same "specifications" is not showing up either.  The part is labled on its side: R1705DB2 200uH 2A 040892-3.  The robot is old and the manufacturer will not release the specifications for the unit.  What I am wondering is of the amps or the inductance, what value can I change, without affecting the rest of the circuit board? When an inductor is labled is current Isat or Irms?

Comment: What do you mean by "coupled"?

Comment: By coupled I mean there are two overlapping windings around a toroidal magnet.  One is connected to a diode and then the drain of a mosfet and then other end is grounded on the board. The other winding is connected to resister, diode, and capacitor in loop.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a CM choke of very low inductance value rated for 2Adc, which is usually the point where L  drops 50%.  The  CM and DM impedance can vary from supplier to supplier but easily matched close enough.

It might also be ok for AC line filter.

High inductance parts for CM or common mode coupled inductors are typically in mH range for AC filter.

Get specs from NDL and parts from http://www.pegasus-components.de/elektronische-bauteile/R1705DB2&index=r&page=6

Then use a better silicone coating for corrosion resistance.